# Is it possible to call groovy script method from command line?

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to call groovy script method from command line without using manual mapping args[]->method_to_call?

For example if I have groovy script 'MyGroovyScript.groovy' like:

```
def foo() {

}

def bar() {

}
```

And I want to call foo() method from command line like:

```
groovy MyGroovyScript.groovy foo
```

Comment: Instead of calling a method from groovy script You can put body of the method in script itself - it will be invoked and processed while script is run.

Comment: @Opal Yes, I know, but this is not what I want actually.

Comment: Any further details on what You exactly looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest I believe you can get is:

```
def foo() {
    println "foo called"
}

def bar() {
    println "bar called"
}

def woo( a, b ) {
    println "Woo called with a=$a and b=$b"
}

static main( args ) {
    if( args ) {
        "${args.head()}"( *args.tail() )
    }
}
```

So then running the following commands give the following outputs:

```
$ groovy test.groovy foo
foo called

$ groovy test.groovy bar
bar called

$ groovy test.groovy woo tim yates
Woo called with a=tim and b=yates
```

Comment: Yes, but OP stated: "without using manual mapping args[]->method_to_call"

Comment: Yeah, this is _"The closest I believe you can get"_ :-/  It's *almost* automatic, and better than checking the args for `foo` or `bar` ;-)

Comment: Looks good, but still didn't get how does it work: '"${args.head()}"( *args.tail() )'. Will try to investigate by myself, anyway thank you! :)

Comment: @XZen `args.head()` gets the first argument, then wrapping it in `"${args.head()}"` makes it a string of this argument, and adding parentheses `"${args.head()}"()` makes it call the function of this name. Then, `args.tail()` returns the args list without the first element, and using the spread operator `*args.tail()` makes each element into an argument for the function call.  So all together, if we say args is `['woo', 'tim', 'yates']` then it expands to `woo( 'tim', 'yates' )`... Nifty! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest form I found meanwhile is the following:

```
groovy -e "new MyGroovyScript().foo()"
```

If you want to pass "MyGroovyScript" and "foo" as space-separated arguments, you can play with bash commands. Probably there are some nicer options, but one of them:

```
bash -c 'groovy -e "new $0().$1()"' MyGroovyScript foo
```